# Loop over a list of variables and generate a test

Tags: r

I would like to write a loop that generates the following text :

```
fcor, out= "variable"
{
trait= "variable"
interclass_weight = "uniform"
intraclass_weight = "uniform"
standard_error = "true", conservative, pairs
type = "both", tabular
sex_name = "true"
homogeneity_test = "true", all
generation_limit = "2"
}
```

each time with a different variable name (I have over all 353 variables).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've been down voted for not showing effort. I'll get you started with what you need:

First - you will need to build it up using a combination of escape quotes `/"` and newlines `/n` with a function like `cat` - with the `sep=""` argument set so as to avoid gaps between elements of your string.

For instance

```
> variable = "and"
> cat("blah= \"", variable, "\"\nmore blah", sep="")

blah= "and"
more blah
```

Second to do it for a series of variables a `for` loop is simple

```
> variable <- LETTERS[1:3]
> for(L in variable)
>    cat("blah= \"", L, "\"\nmore blah\n", sep="")

blah= "A"
more blah
blah= "B"
more blah
blah= "C"
more blah
```

I leave the precise details of your example to you.

Comment: Thanks, it was great help (I admit I am a little lazy...), here is what I wrote: data<-NULL

for (i in clist) {
cat("\nfcor, out=  \"", i,"\"\n{","\ntrait=\"", i,"\"\ninterclass_weight = \"","uniform","\"\nintraclass_weight =  \"", "uniform"
,"\"\nstandard_error = \"","true", "\", conservative, pairs","\ntype = \"","both","\", tabular","\nsex_name =\"", "true","\"\nhomogeneity_test = \"","true", "\", all","\ngeneration_limit = \"", "2", "\"\n}",sep="")
data<-rbind(data,data1)
}         One more problem- the results are printed on the console and I can not output them. Where is my mistake?

Comment: If the answer works then accept it as the correct answer pls. Check the `sink()` function help examples, something like `sink(file.txt"); your for loop...; sink();`